# g++ error "sstream.tcc:112:39: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token"

Tags: c++, g++

I tried to install install one program at Ubuntu and it uses main.cpp .I dont know why but it gives always error.(main.cpp syntax correct 100%) and this program works without error @Mac system but not ubuntu.I couldnt know to how to fix it.Please can you help that issue?

g++ version : g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

Error below:

```
g++ -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -I/usr/include/mysql    -c -o main.o main.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/sstream:580:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:44,
                 from main.cpp:13:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/sstream.tcc: In member function ‘virtual std::basic_stringbuf<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::int_type std::basic_stringbuf<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::overflow(std::basic_stringbuf<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::int_type)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/sstream.tcc:112:39: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/sstream.tcc:114:35: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Please post the relevant lines from sstream.h, main.cpp, etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[A Google search for that error message](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=sstream.tcc%3A112%3A39%3A+error%3A+expected+unqualified-id+before&rlz=1CAGGAB_enAU532AU532&oq=sstream.tcc%3A112%3A39%3A+error%3A+expected+unqualified-id+before) suggests [this is caused by a macro `max` interfering with code in `sstream.h`](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/507592-any-tips-finding-problematic-line-code).  Try adding these lines just above where it is included in `main.cpp`:

```
#undef max
#undef min
```